# How to architect team-based chat?

Tags: twilio-conversations

We are evaluating a chat solution for a system we are developing. Twilio Conversations is our preferred option, as we also plan to use video. Our requirement seems to be a bit atypical of most solutions, and we are trying to determine the best architecture.

The solution is for a healthcare provider. Patients will be able to chat, via a mobile app, to a number of teams in the clinic, who will converse via a web app. Clinic staff can belong to several Teams. Chats can be initiated at both sides.

We are trying to determine the best architecture for Team members. Chat responses should come from the team, not an individualand any team member should be able to continue a conversation.

So, do we have one chat user per team? This seems to make sense, except a Team member could be in several teams, so we would need to handle multiple identities.

Or do we create a group comprising each team member plus the patient? This doesn't seem the rightr approach. We would need to hide the individual user identities, keep responses in sync using horizons, and I doubt would scale well?

I'm surpised this isn't a common scenario, so was wondering if there ws a recommended architecture? Thx

Comment: No need to reply. We have decided to roll-our-own solution :)

Comment: I am wondering the same thing.. I am feeling like the conversation api is too limited and it better to implment it myself by using the sms,whatsapp and chat api seperatly